# ViewPagerIndicator: control tab width or visibility individually

Tags: java, android, viewpagerindicator

I have 4 tabs in TabPageIndicator and want tabs after 3rd one to be gone completely, i.e. would like to focus to corresponding fragments by pressing some other controls, but their tabs should not be visible in any way.
I tried modifying `addTab` as shown below, but it does not seem to help:

```
private void addTab(int index, CharSequence text, int iconResId) {
    final TabView tabView = new TabView(getContext());
    tabView.mIndex = index;
    tabView.setFocusable(true);
    tabView.setOnClickListener(mTabClickListener);
    tabView.setText(text);

    if (iconResId != 0) {
        tabView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, iconResId, 0, 0);
    }

    if (index>3) 
    {   
        tabView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mTabLayout.addView(tabView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                0, 0));
    } else
    mTabLayout.addView(tabView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
            MATCH_PARENT, 1));
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Found this stupid mistake:

```
if (index>3)
```

should be

```
if (index>2)
```

as Tabs are numbered from 0, not from 1.

Comment: Can you add a description what you try to achieve please. Because your approach seems a bit weird to me. Maybe we can help you when you describe what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @viperbone It's OK, I already found a mistake (it should be `index>2`) and it works. Nevertheless, I needed following - no tabs visible for pages after the third one, only pages themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was just plain stupidity - "after 3rd one" does not translate to

```
   if (index>3) {..}
```

Tabs are indexed from 0, so it should be

```
   if (index>2) {..}
```

Comment: I could not find question like this here, so I guess someone may use it and I won't delete it.